# How to access top level functions referring to the file they're declared in?

Tags: kotlin

If you have a file `MyUtils.kt` in app/utils/:

```
package app.utils

fun log(message: String) {
    println(message)
}
```

And you want to access this `log()` function from another file `App.kt` at app/, you will do this:

```
package app

import app.utils.log

fun main() {
   log("hey")
}
```

But I don't like how the `log()` function is imported from the /utils package and not from the `MyUtils.kt` file explicitly.
One alternative would be to declare `MyUtils.kt` with `package app.utils.MyUtils` but I don't think it's a good practice to declare files in packages that don't have a matching folder.

Is there a way around this?

Edit: declaring an `object` or `class` wouldn't be a good solution either because of memory issues.

Comment: *declaring an object or class wouldn't be a good solution either because of memory issues.*: what memory issues? Anyway, that's how top-level functions work, just accept it. Top-level classes, and are imported from a package. Same for top-level functions.

Comment: Not to mention that there's no such thing as a top-level function in bytecode, so you'll have a wrapping class for your function regardless if you're running on the JVM.

Comment: That's just the way it's structured. It's technically in `MyUtilsKt.java` once compiled, but Kotlin just references it as a part of the package

Comment: @JBNizet If I put it in a `class` then I'd have to initiate it every where I want to use my function, if I put it in an `object` then I'll have issues once I need to pass heavy references to my functions in it if I'm not using any decent dependency injection system.

Comment: Objects are singletons. I don't get what you mean and why you would need to use a DI system to use a function defined in an object. But again, as I said, you shouldn't be bothered by importing a top-level fuction from package.

Comment: In the minimal example it wouldn't be a problem, but say that instead of `log(String)` I have `log(obj: LargeObject)`, if it were in a singleton, the instance of `LargeObject` that I pass to it will now be retained for the entire lifetime of the singleton, i.e. until the application dies. At least this is what I've always thought, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, it won't. You don't save it in a field of the singleton object, so why would it be kept in memory?

Comment: I thought it would... Time for some testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can't.

**Long answer**

You seem to have a misconception that a class or object somehow adds some *memory issues* to your application.

That's not the case.

In fact, if you're running on the JVM, your log function will compile to the following:

```
public final class UtilsKt {
    public static final void log(@NotNull String message) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(message, "message");
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

You can hit `Meta+Shift+A` on IntelliJ, then do `Show Kotlin bytecode` if you don't believe me.

Also, you seem to believe it should be possible to refer to a file name explicitly in a Kotlin import. There isn't a way to do that. Files have almost no bearings on the Kotlin compiled-code (it's kind of an accident that the file name actually reflects on the generated Java class name, as shown above).

Packages in Kotlin are usually arranged to meet the directories they are in... but that's not mandatory, by the way. You can write classes in several packages under the same directory. This means that the file names and even directory names do not really affect Kotlin runtime types and imports.

If you are worried about not being able to quickly find out where your functions are declared, I suggest you use the Java convention of calling the files by the name of the class that live in it, and then wrap all functions into an `object` (there's absolutely no runtime costs associated with that).

```
package app.utils

object MyUtils {
    fun log(message:String) => println(message)
}
```

**File: app/utils/MyUtils.kt**

But notice that with any decent IDE, navigating to the declaration of a function is trivial (Meta+B in IntelliJ, usually) regardless of in which file it is in, so this problem is not normally an issue when you work with an IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. For some reason I was convinced that functions inside singletons would keep a reference to the arguments passed to them, which now thinking about it wouldn't make much sense, anyway thanks for clearing it up.